# CSS character encoding @charset

Tags: css, character-encoding

What is the difference between charset name set lowercase or uppercase. Or it should be all CAPS?

@charset "UTF-8"; or @charset "utf-8";

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference in practical terms.  According to the [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets):

> The character set names may be up to 40 characters taken from the
>   printable characters of US-ASCII.  **However, no distinction is made
>   between use of upper and lower case letters.**

Each encoding has a *canonical name*, which is the official name.

[The complete official list of IANA-assigned names and aliases is here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets).

For example:

- the official name of `UTF-8` is `UTF-8`
- the official name of `US-ASCII` is actually `ANSI_X3.4-1968`, but these are all proper aliases: `US-ASCII`, `iso-ir-6`, `ANSI_X3.4-1986`, `ISO_646.irv:1991`, `ASCII`, `ISO646-US`, `us`, `IBM367`, `cp367`, `csASCII`
- the official name of `latin8` is `ISO-8859-14`, with aliases `latin8`, `iso-ir-199`, `ISO_8859-14:1998`, `ISO_8859-14`, `iso-celtic`, `l8`

Not all implementations support the full set of IATA encodings and alias names; so you might want to test carefully if you're going to use something that isn't mainstream.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset

In your example, it should be UTF-8 (uppercase), but it doesn't have to be all uppercase. latin8, for example, is lowercase.